# ImageMagick `display` on MS Windows

Tags: windows, imagemagick

Is there a way to use ImageMagick's `display` command-line tool on MS Windows?

As far as I know, [it requires an X Window System](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/display.php), which MS Windows does not have. Yet, the MS Windows binary come with `display` bundled in, as well. If it can't be used for viewing, is there anything else I can use it for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are third party components for MS Windows which provide an X Window System. See for example here: **http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/**.

If you install an X Window System on MS Windows, `display.exe` will work with this.

However, any ImageMagick installation on MS Windows should also include another utilitity, *`imdisplay.exe`*.

This will work on Windows without an X Window System, and provide similar options as the original `display` utility does....